# Why is my Deliver BroadcastReceiver never getting called?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, android-broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

I'm sending a message via SmsManager and my Send Receiver seems to be working exactly as expected but my Delivery Receiver doesn't appear to be getting called.

```
public void sendSms(BaseFragment fragment, String address, String message) {

    if (isSimAvailable(fragment)) {
        try {
            String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
            String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

            PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(fragment.getContext(), 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
            PendingIntent deliverPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(fragment.getContext(), 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

            fragment.getContext().registerReceiver(new SentReceiver(), new IntentFilter(SENT));
            fragment.getContext().registerReceiver(new DeliverReceiver(), new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

            SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsMgr.sendTextMessage(address, null, message, sentPI, deliverPI);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(fragment.getContext(), e.getMessage() + "!\n" + "Failed to send SMS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(fragment.getContext(), "Cannot send SMS because SIM is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

class DeliverReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Text delivered",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(context, "sms_not_delivered",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }

    }
}

class SentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Sent text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(context, "No service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I've added the following 4 permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
```

Again, I'm able to send texts find and the onReceive for my Sent Receiver is getting invoked.  It's just the onReceive on my Deliver Receiver that is not getting invoked.

I'm doing my testing on AT&T network, if that makes a difference.  I do remember reading somewhere that some networks don't send delivery reports back but I would be shocked if that were the case for AT&T.

Comment: AT&T does not offer delivery reports for SMS.

Comment: try in multiple device ... check whether its device specific

Comment: Mike, is there any documentation or even better a way to programmatically determine which providers do and which ones don't?   I was relying on the delivery report to execute some business logic and I want to know when I should resort to the sent confirmation instead.

Comment: "is there any documentation" - For what, exactly? "or...a way to programmatically determine which providers do and which ones don't?" - Not as far as I know. I really doubt it. "I was relying on the delivery report to execute some business logic" - Yeah, don't. You can't rely on a delivery report. If you want to use it if it's available, then I would say the usual method is to put a timeout on it. If after, say, 10 seconds, you don't get the report, then proceed based on the sent result.

Comment: Just to close the loop on this, tried a t-mobile sim on the sender device and it worked like a charm.  I actually wasn't sure if I also needed to send the message to a non-ATT sim but  it looks like only the app host device needs to support delivery report.   Mike M, makes sense.